# argument 1 must have a "write" method - creating csv file from json

Tags: python, json, csv

I am making a call to the AWS API using `boto3` and `Python` and I am writing the `JSON` response to a `JSON`file. I am then trying to convert the `JSON` file to a `CSV` file. When I attempt to do this with the `csv writer()` method, I get the above error and I am not sure why.

**Code:**

```
def ResponseConvert():
    dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')

    response = dynamo.scan(
    TableName='XXXX'
    )

    with open('vuln_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(response, outfile, indent=4)

    f = open('vuln_data.json')
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()

    f = csv.writer(open('vuln_data.csv', 'wb+'))

    f.writerow(data.keys())
    for row in data:
        f.writerow(row.values())

ResponseConvert()
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "response_convert.py", line 21, in <module>
    ResponseConvert()
  File "response_convert.py", line 19, in ResponseConvert
    f.writerow(row.values())
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: You haven't actually included a traceback but I assume the error originates from `output = csv.writer('vuln_data.csv')`. Open the file (`with open('vuln_data.csv', 'w') as outfile:`) and then pass `outfile` to `writer`

Comment: This doesn't error out, but nothing gets written to the file. I have a full `json` file but, there is no data in the `csv` file.

Comment: Then what is "argument 1 must have a "write" method"?

Comment: That was the original error from my original code before I tried what you suggested. I have edited the question with the full traceback.

Comment: I don't see a full traceback.

Comment: Check again. It's there.

Comment: Ok, so the traceback complains about exactly the line I guessed in my very first comment. You'll have to do some debugging your end if you're getting no output or error after the change

Answer (score 1):

CSV writers expect a file handle, not a filename.

```
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    ...
```

You probably want a `DictWriter` instead, by the way.  Don't rely on the order of `keys` and `values` matching up.

Comment: I put that in my initial comment but apparently the OP gets an empty file and no error.

Comment: @roganjosh likely PEBKAC

Comment: I edited the code, but now I am getting a new error: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'`. I have updated the code and traceback in the initial question.